# How to decrypt Zend2 encrypted data?

Tags: php, python, zend-framework, encryption

I'm using [Zend2 Crypt module](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.crypt.block-cipher.html) to encrypt a data. Here's my code.

```
$cipher = BlockCipher::factory('mcrypt', array(
  'algorithm' => 'aes',
));
$cipher->setKey('mypassphrase');
$encrypted = $cipher->encrypt('Hey, I am the secret data');
```

Cool, it works well! Now, I need to decrypt that `$encrypted` data (Hey, I am the secret data) in Python.

I am using pycrypto to do that. What the steps to decrypt data outside my PHP environment?

```
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES
    import base64
    import hashlib

    password = 'mypassphrase'
    key = hashlib.sha256(password).digest()

    decoded = base64.standard_b64decode(encrypted)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC)
    data = cipher.decrypt(decoded)
```

I need to specify an `IV` because Zend uses MODE_CBC by default. How can I specify it in my Python code?

Here's the Zend2 documentation:

> The output of the encryption is a string, encoded in Base64 (default), that contains the HMAC value, the IV vector, and the encrypted text. The encryption mode used is the CBC (with a random IV by default) and SHA256 as default hash algorithm of the HMAC. The Mcrypt adapter encrypts using the PKCS#7 padding mechanism by default. You can specify a different padding method using a special adapter for that (Zend\Crypt\Symmetric\Padding). The encryption and authentication keys used by the BlockCipher are generated with the PBKDF2 algorithm, used as key derivation function from the user’s key specified using the setKey() method.

Can someone help me to adapt my Python code to decrypt the data?
Thanks

Comment: Excuse me, but just producing any AES code that uses `mypassphrase` doesn't cut it for me. Where is PBKDF2 and HMAC gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to decrypt the data encrypted by Zend2. Here's my code:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256, HMAC
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2

# The hmac starts from 0 to 64 (length).
hmac_size = 64
hmac = data[:hmac_size]

# The cipher text starts after the hmac to the end.
# The cipher text is base64 encoded, so I decoded it.
ciphertext = data[hmac_size:]
ciphertext = b64decode(ciphertext)

# The IV starts from 0 to 16 (length) of the ciphertext.
iv = ciphertext[:16]

# The key size is 256 bits -> 32 bytes.
key_size = 32

# The passphrase of the key.
password = 'mypassphrase'

# The key is generated using PBKDF2 Key Derivation Function.
# In the case of Zend2 Crypt module, the iteration number is 5000, 
# the result length is the key_size * 2 (64) and the HMAC is computed
# using the SHA256 algorithm
the_hash = PBKDF2(password, iv, count=5000, dkLen=64, prf=lambda p, s:
                  HMAC.new(p, s, SHA256).digest())

# The key starts from 0 to key_size (32).
key = the_hash[:key_size]

# The hmac key starts after the key to the end.
key_hmac = the_hash[key_size:]

# HMAC verification
hmac_new = HMAC.new(key_hmac, 'aes%s' % ciphertext, SHA256).hexdigest()
if hmac_new != hmac:
    raise Exception('HMAC verification failed.')

# Instanciate the cipher (AES CBC).
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)

# It's time to decrypt the data! The ciphertext starts after the IV (so, 16 after).
data = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[16:])
```

**Mission succeeded!**

Comment: Quick question: I know this is an old question, but how did you find out that you needed to append some text to the ciphertext for the hmac validation ('aes%s' % ciphertext)? I looked at the ZF2 documentation but I could not find any reference to this. thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm currently struggling with this exact same issue (Except I'm decrypting in Java). The BlockCipher class in Zend Crypt shows that it's appending the algorithm name to the ciphertext when calculating the hash. https://github.com/zendframework/zend-crypt/blob/757e4fcfa321585833aebca688d319c2c52d319e/src/BlockCipher.php

Look at line 438